# Xcode 5 Continuous Integration workspace errors

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode5

I've been diving into the wonderful world of Continuous Integration using the new tools bundled with Xcode 5, and I've been having a few issues.

First, I have a project that is built using workspaces, and in the workspace there is a project and a static library. The static library is loaded as it's own project in the workspace along with the project file. The library is linked in the project correctly, and I have no problems performing builds on my local development machine.

In the workspace I have created a build scheme for my project. It builds the targets for both the library, and the project it's self. I also selected the workspace as the container of the scheme and I have shared the scheme so that Xcode build tools can access it. Once competed I pushed the changes to my repository.

In Xcode I created a bot to generate an archive every day at midnight, and that has successfully integrated. However, whenever I try to manually run the bot I get the following errors.

```
Skipping archive action as the scheme is not archivable.
Error saving invocation record to resultBundlePath:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “Info.plist” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x7fa32a58a9f0 {NSFilePath=/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-920b070f-7017-4399-8abe-f6304d3c41a8.bundle/output/xcodebuild_result.bundle/Info.plist, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa32a56b110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

I have checked the directory on my OS X Server and the xcodebuild_result.bundle is not being created. I have verified that the system has read/write permissions to these files, and I have even tried to open them up to everyone. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: No one has any info on this at all??